# Implementation of Minimum Vertex Cover in a Bipartite Graph

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a bipartite graph that's quite large (~200 vertices per part, usually with 20,000 or more edges in between), and I'm trying to find a Minimum Vertex Cover in it because I'm looking for an assignment between the vertices of the two parts.

According to Koenig's theorem, there is such a cover with the same size as the cardinality of a Maximum Matching (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)).

I have implemented the Hopcroft Karp algorithm which gives me a Maximum Matching. If needed, I can provide my implementation of that, but I doubt that's where my problem is.

**What's the actual problem?**
I suspect my implementation, taken from the Wikipedia article above (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)#Constructive_proof), has an error in it, but after several hours of checking it I am unable to find the cause of the bug: While the Hopcroft Karp algorithm finds a maximum matching with *192* edges, the Minimum Vertex Cover returns *200* vertices. As this is a bipartite graph, these numbers shouldn't differ (because of the theorem). Maybe you can help me out and tell me where my mistake is. Thanks in advance!!

(`Student`'s and `Project`'s are my two types of vertices in the bipartite graph)

```
internal static List<Vertex> FindMinimumVertexCover(IReadOnlyList<Edge> matching, IReadOnlyList<Vertex> studentVertices, IReadOnlyList<Vertex> projectVertices)
    {
        var unmatchedStudentNodes = studentVertices.Except(matching.Select(e => e.GetStudentVertex())).ToList();
        var visitedVertices = new List<Vertex>();
        var edgeComparer = new EdgeComparer();

        foreach (var unmatchedStudentNode in unmatchedStudentNodes)
        {
            visitedVertices = visitedVertices.Union(FindAlternatingNodes(matching, unmatchedStudentNode, visitedVertices, edgeComparer)).ToList();
        }

        visitedVertices = unmatchedStudentNodes.Union(visitedVertices).ToList();

        return studentVertices.Except(visitedVertices).Union(projectVertices.Intersect(visitedVertices)).ToList();
    }

private static List<Vertex> FindAlternatingNodes(IReadOnlyList<Edge> matching, Vertex initialVertex, List<Vertex> visitedVertices, EdgeComparer edgeComparer)
    {
        if (visitedVertices.Contains(initialVertex))
            return Enumerable.Empty<Vertex>().ToList();

        visitedVertices.Add(initialVertex);
        List<Edge> unmatchedEdges = initialVertex.Edges.Except(matching, edgeComparer).ToList();

        foreach (Edge unmatchedEdge in unmatchedEdges)
        {
            Vertex visitedVertex = unmatchedEdge.GetProjectVertex();
            Edge matchedEdge = matching.SingleOrDefault(e => e.GetProjectVertex().Equals(visitedVertex));

            if (matchedEdge != default(Edge))
            {
                visitedVertices.Add(visitedVertex);
                visitedVertex = matchedEdge.GetStudentVertex();
                visitedVertices = visitedVertices.Union(FindAlternatingNodes(matching, visitedVertex, visitedVertices, edgeComparer)).ToList();
            }
        }

        return visitedVertices;
    }

class EdgeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Edge>
{
    public bool Equals(Edge x, Edge y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (x is null || y is null)
            return false;

        return Object.ReferenceEquals(x.GetStudentVertex(), y.GetStudentVertex()) && Object.ReferenceEquals(x.GetProjectVertex(), y.GetProjectVertex());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Edge edge)
    {
        return (Student: edge.GetStudentVertex(), Project: edge.GetProjectVertex()).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's easy to verify a matching (not necessarily maximum), it's easy to verify a vertex cover (not necessarily minimum), and it's easy to verify that they have the same size (hence both optimal by LP duality). This means that you can do fully automated testing on small random graphs, which I guarantee from experience will flush out the problem. Then you can choose one graph that reproduces the bug, solve it by hand, and apply standard debugging techniques.

Comment: Seems like an interesting question, but it needs a [mcve]. I suspect that you can reproduce the problem with a much smaller graph. Assuming that the graph you tried has 200 vertices per part, then my guess is that the algorithm is simply returning **all** of the vertices in one part. That would guarantee coverage since all edges are between the two parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found the problem. I want to thank @David Eisenstat, as he suggested generating small random graphs repeatedly.

The problem was something in my implementation of the `Vertex` class.

Every time I create an instance of the `Edge` class, I add that Edge to the corresponding vertices as well (meaning I effectively got 3 references to an edge). Calling the outer algorithm again (which calls the method above) only recreated the edge list, but left the old references in the vertices intact. Thus, following calls didn't start freshly, and the Minimum Vertex Cover found edges in the graph that weren't existent anymore (namely the `List<Edge> unmatchedEdges = initialVertex.Edges.Except(matching, edgeComparer).ToList();` line).